# Yii::app()->user->isGuest always returns true even though login was successful

Tags: authentication, logging, yii

I started to make some differences between those users which have authenticated and those that not. For this, i am using

```
Yii::app()->user->id;
```

However, in a determined view i put the following code:

```
<?php 
    if(Yii::app()->user->isGuest) {
        print("Welcome back Guest!");
        print("Your id is ".Yii::app()->user->id);
    } else {
        print("Welcome back ".Yii::app()->user->name);
        print("Your id is ".Yii::app()->user->id);
}?>
```

And i always get the "welcome back guest!", whether i have logged in (successfully) or not. And if i *have* logged in, then it displays the welcome message together with the user's id!

**EDIT**

@briiC.lv
Hey.. sorry for the late reply, I hope you are still following this! I am not extending the given UserIdentity class. Is this mandatory? Since i still dont get very well the whole authorization issue, i thought it would be best to give a try with the class they provide, and then extend with my own functionality.. Anyway, next i post my UserIdentity class with its small tweaks.. maybe the problem lies here??

```
<?php class UserIdentity extends CUserIdentity{
private $_id;

public function authenticate()
{   
    $user = Users::model()->findAll('username=\''.$this->username.'\' AND password=\''.$this->encryptedPassword.'\'');
    if(!isset($user[0]))
    {
        return false;
    }
    else 
    {   
        $this->setState('id', $user[0]->id);            
        $this->username = $user[0]->username;
        $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_NONE;
        return true;
    }
}

public function getId()
{
    return $this->_id;
}
```

}

Here is the output i got when i started to log as you suggested; i got this output immediately after successfully logging in.

```
[05:23:21.833][trace][vardump] CWebUser#1 ( 
[allowAutoLogin] => true 
[guestName] => 'Guest' 
[loginUrl] => array ( '0' => '/site/login' ) 
[identityCookie] => null 
[authTimeout] => null 
[autoRenewCookie] => false 
[autoUpdateFlash] => true 
[CWebUser:_keyPrefix] => '0f4431ceed8f17883650835e575b504b' 
[CWebUser:_access] => array() 
[behaviors] => array() 
[CApplicationComponent:_initialized] => true 
[CComponent:_e] => null 
[CComponent:_m] => null 
)
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: hi! im still here :) Pleae add user loging script that includes line similar to *$identity = new UserIdentity( $username, $password );* and how you handling loging further

Comment: OFTOPIC: in userIdentity don't use *findAll*. Use *find* instead, because you want find only one person. And you can use *$user* varibale as model object *$user->id* instead of *$user[0]->id*

Comment: Did you ever manage to solve this?

Comment: This problem happened to me because sessions weren't being saved correctly on the PHP side of things, not because of something in Yii.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe you can try to debug harder:
change messages to something like this:

```
if(Yii::app()->user->isGuest) {
    print("Not logged");
} else {
    print_r(Yii::app()->user);
    print("Welcome ".Yii::app()->user->name);
    print("Your id is ".Yii::app()->user->id);

}
```

And check session variable in your config/main.php file

```
...
    'session' => array(
        'autoStart'=>true,
    ),
...
```

Comment: I just tried that but it didnt work. However, doesnt this parameter default to true? This is the relevant part -i think, of my config file:

 `'components'=>array(
  'user'=>array(
   // enable cookie-based authentication
   'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
  ),
  'session' => array (
   'autoStart' => true,
  ),`

I have very very little experience with web authentication altogether, so I am clueless to where the problem might be. Thanks por your help though, any other suggestion or code snippet that could reveal the problem? Thank you!

Comment: Ha.  Why is it so many php programers think debugging is printing out variables.  Wouldn't it make more sense to use netbeans and a real debugger?  You can even watch the code run in real time and set a break point to stop it.  Genius!

Comment: **@k to the z**

Well, as much as i would love to do _that_ kind of debugging, when i started out with this framework (a month ago) i dedicated a few days trying to figure out how to debug and couldnt. Since i couldnt afford losing more time, i turned to the old fashioned way... placing print() commands just about anywhere! though one could debate how much time im actually gaining...

I still havent been able to resolve this it is driving me crazy!!

Comment: **@k to the z** (and **@Soph** ) Yii have buil-in debugging : **Yii::log(...)** (search it with **WebLogRoute**). But about authorization.. try add debugging to your userIdentity class (if you extending it). and check maybe you are destroying session somewhere?

Comment: In the config for your authManager, check to see if defaultRoles contains guest.  The default roles will be assigned to all users everytime logged in or not.

Answer (score 4):

The error is in the following line

```
$this->setState('id', $user[0]->id);
```

As seen in the [official yii documentation regarding auth & auth](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.auth), `setState` should be used for anything *but* the id field. In order to implement the key Yii will use to identify your user, return a unique value per user in the Identity `getId()` function.

In your case, this means you simply have to change the above line into the following:

```
$this->_id = $user[0]->id;
```

Regarding the actual inner working of the login procedure, I'd recommend a look at the `CWebUser` class, and especially at its [login function](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebUser#login-detail), which is responsible for the actual storage of the Identity `getId()` return value.

Answer (score 1):

when you call authenticate function login user as

```
 $userIdentity = new UserIdentity($username, $password);   
        $userIdentity->authenticate();
        if ($userIdentity->errorCode===UserIdentity::ERROR_NONE) {
            Yii::app()->user->login($userIdentity,0);
 }
```

and fetch id as

```
echo 'id='.Yii::app()->user->getId();
```

apply this code and check

Answer (score 1):

I have faced same problem and found that only one line in UserIdentity Component will resolve this issue.

This is your code:

```
else 
{   
    $this->setState('id', $user[0]->id);            
    $this->username = $user[0]->username;
    $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_NONE;
    return true;
}
```

Update this code by this one

```
else 
{
    $this->_id = $user[0]->id;   
    $this->setState('id', $user[0]->id);            
    $this->username = $user[0]->username;
    $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_NONE;
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to know condition that sets guest and logged-in user apart.

Based on Yii master's branch [CWebUser::getIsGuest()](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/master/framework/web/auth/CWebUser.php#L277):

```
public function getIsGuest()
{
    return $this->getState('__id')===null;
}
```

Compared to your code:

```
$user = Users::model()->findAll('username=\''.$this->username.'\' AND password=\''.$this->encryptedPassword.'\'');
if(!isset($user[0])) {
    // false
} else {   
    $this->setState('id', $user[0]->id); // this is for persistent state sakes
    ...
}
```

}

In short: you did supply 'id' to Identity persistent state but Yii CWebUser expecting '__id' based on UserIdentity::getId().

Solution is pretty dead simple. You just need to set $this->_id

```
$user = Users::model()->findAll('username=\''.$this->username.'\' AND password=\''.$this->encryptedPassword.'\'');
if(!isset($user[0])) {
    // false
} else {   
    $this->setState('id', $user[0]->id); // this is for persistent state sakes
    $this->_id = $user[0]->id; // this is UserIdentity's ID that'll be fetch by CWebUser
    ...
}
```

}

This routine explains how CWebUser get UserIdentity's ID: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/master/framework/web/auth/CWebUser.php#L221

Please do test it out.

Comment: as a side note. `$this->_id` or whatever instance variable name can be use as long as it's returned by `UserIdentity::getId()`

Answer (score 0):

Please try following code. Its working well

```
//config/main.php
return array (
'component' => array(
    'session' => array(
        'savePath' => INSTANCE_ROOT.DS.'runtime'.DS.'session',
        'autoStart' => true,
        ),
    )
);

// LoginController 
class LoginController extends CController {
    public function actionLogin () {
      if(isset($_POST['LoginForm']))
      {
          $form = new LoginForm;
          $form->setAttributes($_POST['LoginForm']);

          if ($form->validate()) {
                $user = Users::model()->find('upper(username) = :username', array(
                    ':username' => strtoupper($form->username)));

                    if($user)
                        return $this->authenticate($user, $form);
                    else {
                        Yii::log( 'som.....', 'error');
                        $form->addError('password', Yii::t('Username or Password is incorrect'));
                    }
                    return false;
          }
      }
    }

    protected function authenticate($user, $form) {
        $identity = new UserIdentity($user->username, $form->password);
        $identity->authenticate();
        switch($identity->errorCode) {
            case UserIdentity::ERROR_NONE:
                $duration = $form->rememberMe ? 3600*24*30 : 0; // 30 days
                Yii::app()->user->login($identity,$duration);
                return $user;
                break;
            case UserIdentity::ERROR_EMAIL_INVALID:
                $form->addError("password",Yii::t('Username or Password is incorrect'));
                break;
            case UserIdentity::ERROR_STATUS_INACTIVE:
                $form->addError("status",Yii::t('This account is not activated.'));
                break;
            case UserIdentity::ERROR_STATUS_BANNED:
                $form->addError("status",Yii::t('This account is blocked.'));
                break;
            case UserIdentity::ERROR_STATUS_REMOVED:
                $form->addError('status', Yii::t('Your account has been deleted.'));
                break;
            case UserIdentity::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID:
                Yii::log( Yii::t(
                            'Password invalid for user {username} (Ip-Address: {ip})', array(
                                '{ip}' => Yii::app()->request->getUserHostAddress(),
                                '{username}' => $form->username)), 'error');
                    if(!$form->hasErrors())
                    $form->addError("password",Yii::t('Username or Password is incorrect'));
                break;
                return false;
        }
    }
}

class UserIdentity extends CUserIdentity {

    const ERROR_EMAIL_INVALID=3;
    const ERROR_STATUS_INACTIVE=4;
    const ERROR_STATUS_BANNED=5;
    const ERROR_STATUS_REMOVED=6;
    const ERROR_STATUS_USER_DOES_NOT_EXIST=7;

    public function authenticate()
    {
        $user = Users::model()->find('username = :username', array(
                    ':username' => $this->username));
        if(!$user)
            return self::ERROR_STATUS_USER_DOES_NOT_EXIST;

        if(Users::encrypt($this->password)!==$user->password)
            $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
        else if($user->status == YumUser::STATUS_INACTIVE)
            $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_STATUS_INACTIVE;
        else if($user->status == YumUser::STATUS_BANNED)
            $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_STATUS_BANNED;
        else if($user->status == YumUser::STATUS_REMOVED)
            $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_STATUS_REMOVED;

        return !$this->errorCode;
    }
}

class Users extends CActiveModel
{
    const STATUS_INACTIVE = 0;
    const STATUS_ACTIVE = 1;
    const STATUS_BANNED = -1;
    const STATUS_REMOVED = -2;

    // some ..........

    public static function encrypt($string = "")
    {
        $salt = 'salt';
        $string = sprintf("%s%s%s", $salt, $string, $salt);
        return md5($string);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check your security configuration for cookies and sessions.
disable **session.use_only_cookies** & **session.cookie_httponly** in php.ini
 file.

Answer (score 0):

in PHP.INI => session.use_only_cookies = 0

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It would improve your answer a lot if you could explain a little how this solves the problem.