# Yii Authentication error: After login successfull Yii::app()->user->isGuest() always return true

Tags: php, yii

I started creating a difference between the authenticated users and guest user. But always when i identify the user and it get the login successfully, it still returns true when i make use Yii::app()->user->isGuest. Here is the code which i am using:

```
if (Yii::app()->user->isGuest){
            echo 'Welcome back Guest';
    } else {
            echo 'Welcome back '.Yii::app()->user->name;
    }
```

I always get the 'welcome back guest', whether i have logged in (successfully) or not. And if i have logged in again i got this message. and here is the User Identify code.

```
class UserIdentity extends CUserIdentity {

    /**
     * Authenticates a user.
     */
    private $_id;

    public function authenticate() {
        $user = Users::model()->findByAttributes(array('username' => $this->username));
        if ($user === null)
            $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID;
        else if ($user->password !== $this->password)
            $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
        else {
            $this->_id = $user->id;
            $this->setState('title', $this->username);
            $this->setState('id', $user->id);   
            $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_NONE;
        }
        return !$this->errorCode;
    }

    public function getId() {
        return $this->_id;
    }

}
```

Please help me to get rid of this problem.

Comment: Is the user actually logging in somewhere?

Comment: yes, when ever i used to log in the Yii::app()->user->name returns the name but as i use the Yii::app()->user->id, it return null.

Comment: Try using Yii::app()->user->getId(); and check using var_dump whats the result for Yii::app()->user->isGuest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should fix [LoginForm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16822528/login-module-error-property-loginform-id-is-not-defined/16823026#16823026)

```
/**
 * Authenticates the password.
 * This is the 'authenticate' validator as declared in rules().
 */
public function authenticate($attribute, $params)
{
    // we only want to authenticate when no input errors
    if (! $this->hasErrors()) {
        $identity = new UserIdentity($this->email, $this->password);
        $identity->authenticate();
        switch ($identity->errorCode) {
            case UserIdentity::ERROR_NONE:
                $duration = ($this->rememberMe)
                    ? 3600*24*14 // 14 days
                    : 0; // login till the user closes the browser
                Yii::app()->user->login($identity, $duration);
                break;

            default:
                // UserIdentity::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID
                // UserIdentity::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID
                // UserIdentity::ERROR_MEMBER_NOT_APPOVED
                $this->addError('', Yii::t('auth',
                    'Incorrect username/password combination.'));
                break;
        }
    }
}


class UsersController extends Controller 
{
    /**
     * Displays the login page
     */
    public function actionLogin() 
    {
        $model = new LoginForm;

        if (isset($_POST['LoginForm'])) {
            $model->attributes = $_POST['LoginForm'];

            $valid = $model->validate();
            if ($valid) {
                $this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl);
            }
        }
        $this->render('login', array('model' => $model));
    }
}
```

Can you show your config?

Comment: **Valery Viktorovsky** i tried the code which you suggested me. The only issue is that after login request it redirect to the home but dosen shows logout menu. As Yii::app()->user->isGuest() return true. Also when i print Yii::app()->user->name, it shows the username. Now what to do? :(

Comment: Maybe cookies are disabled in your browser? Is HTTPS used on your site? Also check your UsersController.

Comment: Thanks **Valery Viktorovsky** i got the solution. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Answer can be found here [yii authentication error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210108/yiiapp-user-isguest-always-returns-true-even-though-login-was-successful)

You can also read more on yii authentication here [authentication and authorisation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.auth)

Comment: Thank u Naselorm, I just go through to these link.

Comment: **Naselorm** i implemented all these tutorials step by step but my problem is still maintained, so please suggest me. :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see using Not(!) operator

```
if (!Yii::app()->user->isGuest){
            echo 'Welcome back Guest';
    } else {
            echo 'Welcome back '.Yii::app()->user->name;
    }
```

Comment: Ninad i used this code but it dosen't meet my requirement. Because still Yii::app()->user->id returns null.

Answer (score 0):

You should **NOT** do this :

```
$this->setState('id', $user[0]->id);
```

setState should not be used for the 'id'. For returning the 'id' you have already overridden the getId() method.

If you do need to set it, change it something like this :

```
$this->_id = $user[0]->id;
```

Hope this helped.

Regards,